# Сохранение XML-файла

Tags: php, xml, header

Имеется XML-файл, лежащий в папке files.

По нажатию на кнопку он "собирается" и должен скачиваться.

Как можно это реализовать серез header (или иным способом), чтобы при сохранение не обнавлялась страница?

Answer (score 0):

если вы знаете про функцию `header`, то это уже хорошо. но не поленитесь прочитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) к ней:

> Если нужно предупредить пользователя о необходимости сохранить пересылаемые данные, такие как сгенерированный PDF-файл, можно воспользоваться заголовком » `Content-Disposition`, который подставляет рекомендуемое имя файла и заставляет браузер показать диалог загрузки.
>   *Пример #1 Диалог загрузки*

```
 // Будем передавать PDF
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

 // Он будет называться downloaded.pdf
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

 // Исходный PDF-файл original.pdf
 readfile('original.pdf');
```

в вашем случае mime-type следует указать `text/xml` или `application/xml`, ну и если файл собирается динамически, то вывести его через `echo/print`:

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root></root>");
 // формируем xml
 // ....
 // сохраняем в файл
 $xml->asXML("/path/to/your/file.xml");

 // отправляем заголовки для скачивания
 header('Content-Type: application/xml');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.xml"');

 // скидываем сам файл
 print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Если файл в папке, то где указать путь до файла?

Comment: @Lyavontiy если файл готовый в какой-то папке, то вообще просто сделайте ссылку на его `<a href="/files/my/file.xml" target="_blank">скачать</a>`

Comment: если же дииректория не доступна снаружи, то соответственно путь указывать надо в `readfile('path/to/my/file.xml')`

Comment: По нажатию кнопки файл должен создаться и в конце скачаться

Comment: @Lyavontiy слегка дополнил ответ